# Mint map number keys to higlight text

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, linux-mint

I have a standard PS2 keyboard hooked up to my Mint linux box.  When I try shift + the arrow keys on the number pad, I just get the numbers typed in.  However I want it to work the same as on my Windows box.  How do I map the arrow keys to highlight using the arrow keys 4,8,2,6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly it is in Mint, but the "Keyboard Layouts" settings panel should have an "Options..." button, which has related settings in it:

- Miscellaneous compatibility options

  - Shift with numeric keypad keys works as in MS Windows (`numpad:microsoft`)

The same options can be set via `setxkbmap -option "numpad:microsoft"`, for example, although this method is only temporary.

Comment: Exactly thnx a lot - it's Control center -> Keyboard