# Mac OS X map number keys to higlight text with a PC keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine

I have a standard PS2 keyboard on my PC running Mac in a VM. When I try shift + the arrow keys on the number pad, I just get the numbers typed in. However I want it to work the same as on my Windows box. How do I map the arrow keys to highlight using the arrow keys 4,8,2,6 ?

It was easy to get it working on the Linux box, 
[Mint map number keys to higlight text](https://superuser.com/questions/351976/mint-map-number-keys-to-higlight-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "$#2" = moveDownAndModifySelection:;
    "$#4" = moveLeftAndModifySelection:;
    "$#6" = moveRightAndModifySelection:;
    "$#8" = moveUpAndModifySelection:;
}
```

The custom keybindings don't work in all applications or views though. Remapping keys with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) usually works almost everywhere.

Comment: The KeyRemap4MacBook seems to work for the most part in xCode